# Word and number connection

Tags: wordplay, language

Connect these following words/phrases:

- Best regards
- Hatsune Miku
- Unofficial
- Miserable
- Heaven
- Rubber
- Meat

To the following numbers:

- 63
- 4649
- 56
- 152
- 39
- .59
- 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution is

> Best regards --- 4649 
>  Hatsune Miku --- 39 
>  Unofficial --- 152 
>  Miserable --- 63 
>  Heaven --- .59 
>  Rubber --- 56 
>  Meat --- 29

because

> The Japanese translations of the English phrases have similar pronunciations as the corresponding numbers in Japanese.

Comment: You can add this [reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay)